# node.js npm error when installing plugins with -g

Tags: node.js, npm

Trying to install express globally and gets this error. I'm running the node.js version 0.10.24 on my x86 qnap.

```
[/share/Qweb/Codiad/workspace/chat] # npm install express -g
npm ERR! Error: setuid user id does not exist
npm ERR! at /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/uid-number.js:44:16
npm ERR! at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:635:7)
npm ERR! at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR! at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
npm ERR! at Socket. (child_process.js:948:11)
npm ERR! at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
npm ERR! at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this entire log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR! http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues

npm ERR! System Linux 3.4.6
npm ERR! command "/opt/bin/node" "/opt/bin/npm" "install" "express" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /share/MD0_DATA/Qweb/Codiad/workspace/chat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR! /share/MD0_DATA/Qweb/Codiad/workspace/chat/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3789

Comment: Same error but no solution :(

Comment: @damphat yes install packages locally seems to work without errors.

Comment: What OS are you using ? looks like `uid-number` package is causing the error for you.

Comment: @damphat running this on a QNAP X86 processor. I dont have the sudo command. There is no root user only admin user in this system.

Comment: @user568109 I'm running on a QNAP x86 system. I think its a modified linux system.

Comment: @damphat i will try that. But when i run process.getuid() it retuns 0.

Comment: @damphat hey thanks its works. Plz post a answer so i can accept it for you. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`npm` tool does not work correctly in [QNAP OS](http://www.qnap.com/)

The **work-around** is telling `npm` that QNAP does not support get or set user-id by modifying `npm` source code:

Open file [uid-number.js](https://github.com/isaacs/uid-number/blob/master/uid-number.js) in your editor:

`/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/uid-‌​number.js`

Goto [line 11](https://github.com/isaacs/uid-number/blob/master/uid-number.js#L11) and replace `uidSupport = process.getuid && process.setuid` with `uidSupport = false`

Answer (score 3):

QNAP lacks couple of system users available on Linux systems and hence some software does not work properly on QNAP with *out-of-the-box* configuration, node included.

Solution to your problem: create user **nobody**. You can use `adduser -D -H nobody`
or NAS's web ui.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Node.js v5.8.0 [download page](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v5.8.0/)

try this: `node-upgrade.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

URL=$1

[[ $URL =~ (node-v5\.8\.0-.*)\.tar\.gz$ ]] && TARFile=${BASH_REMATCH[0]} && DirName=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
[[ $TARFile == "" ]] && echo "url is wrong" && exit

NodeJSPath=$(/sbin/getcfg nodejs Install_Path -f /etc/config/qpkg.conf)

wget --no-check-certificate $URL

tar zxf $TARFile -C $NodeJSPath

rm -r $NodeJSPath/node $TARFile

ln -s $NodeJSPath/$DirName $NodeJSPath/node

uidscript=$NodeJSPath/$DirName/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/uid-number.js
script="$(cat $uidscript)"

echo "${script/", uidSupport = process.getuid && process.setuid"/, uidSupport = false}" > $uidscript
```

e.g.
my qnap nas is Intel x86-based series

```
sh ./node-upgrade.sh https://nodejs.org/download/release/v5.8.0/node-v5.8.0-linux-x86.tar.gz
```